# NMinimise for piecewise objective function with decision variable in the limit/present in the condition

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization, numerical-value

```
 a=7;
c=10;
x1=10;
r1=15;
β=0.1;
δ=0.2;
f[x]=1/(r1-0); 
obj1= Integrate[x f[x],{x,0,r1}]   (a -β i) +i
 
obj2= Integrate[((x1+i δ)(a -β i)+c (x-x1-i δ)2) f[x],{x,x1+i δ,r1}]+i
 NMinimize[{Piecewise[{{obj1, (x1+i δ)>= r1},{obj2,(x1+i δ)<r1}}],i>= 0,i<a/β},{i}]
```

The above code and the below code gives me two different result. Which one is correct and why they are giving two different result.

```
 EFI4=Integrate[x f[x],{x,0,r1-v}]   (a -β i) +Integrate[((x1+i δ)(a -β i)+c (x-x1-i δ)2) f[x],{x,x1+i δ-u,r1}]+i
NMinimize[{EFI4,i<= a/β,u>= 0,v>= 0 ,u*v==0,x1+i δ -r1==u-v,i>= 0},{i,u,v}]
```

Comment: I'm wondering that your first code works. `I ` is predefined and cann't be used as a variable!

Comment: No, it is only in the objective function

Comment: But still  `NMinimize`-parameter is `I`!

Comment: it should be "i." I edited

Comment: I need that in both the objective function....else how will I solve